# How to correctly use Kendo UI template in an anchor tag?

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I'm quite new to Kendo UI template, so please bear with me on this one.

I have an anchor tag which simply render `href` value using the hash `#` template syntax of Kendo UI.  Below is a snippet of the anchor element tag which throws an exception saying "**Invalid template**".

`<a href="/#=routeContext.TenantName##=routeContext.ResourcePrefix#/Entity/#=rmx_AccrualDetail_ViewModel.dataSource.data()[0].rmx_Entity.rmx_EntityId?form##=Customers#" data-bind="text:dataSource.data()[0].rmx_Entity.rmx_Name" target="_blank"></a>`

As an example, I expect the anchor tag would yield the following url: `https://localhost:5002/dev/res/Entity/2?form=Customers`

I also put `\\` to escape the literal equal `=` sign from the url (`form=Customers`), but sadly it didn't work.

Any thoughts or suggestions is highly appreciated?

Comment: i think the error might be around .rmx_EntityId?form##=Customers#, which one is from view model and which one is string?

Comment: i don't really understand what are you doing. try it here https://dojo.telerik.com/OpAnIkif, try to replicate what you are asking with simpler demo. cheers :)

Comment: @himawan_r  thank you for sharing the link.  it's handy to have this.

Comment: @himawan_r `#=rmx_AccrualDetail_ViewModel.dataSource.data()[0].rmx_Entity.rmx_EntityId` this part is from view model, and this one is the string `form##=Customers#`

Comment: if that is the case, you don't need to put on  #= string #, 
only #= data that you wanted to load from view model #
just like what i did on my example